# Toast doesn't works on real device but works fine on emulator

Tags: java, android, toast

I am not exactly sure why this has been happening. I have been doing some research but the situation is too vague that I am even hard time searching for solution.

I created an app using Android Studio, and had been running on a virtual emulator, in which `Toast` function works fine using these two simple lines of code -

```
  Toast temp = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Username and password don't      match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    temp.show();
```

But when I run this on my phone, the app keeps crashing. I have Galaxy Grand Prime, and not even sure if it matters.

Comment: post your logcat details and it will show the error

Comment: Are you calling this bit of code on the main thread? These two lines do not give enough context, they should work in normal cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running from an Activity, do the following

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username and password don't      match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

If this is in a Fragment, don't forget to use `getActivity()`

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Username and password don't      match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

If this is done in a non UI thread, get the context and pass it to the makeText method and use `runOnUIThread` method

```
Toast.makeText(context_of_caller, "Username and password don't      match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```